# How to make Azure Web app to be accessible internally and should not be accessible publicly

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network, azure-private-link

I have a Azure web app that needs to be accessible internally through cooperate network. The web app should not be accessible publicly. To achieve this I did try using access restriction which works if I add the IP address in allow list then add and allow web app inbound address through the VPN. Beside access restriction is there any way to achieve the same functionality so that the internal users do not hit the public IP address and they route internally through private end point?

-Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

> The web app should not be accessible publicly. To achieve this, I did try using access restriction which works.

Using a private endpoint, you can connect securely to a web app.

Created app service with private endpoint like below.

[image]

[image]

Create virtual network with bastion host:

[image]

Created virtual machine with same vnet without public Ip address to access app services in bastion like below:

[image]

[image]

The private endpoint uses an IP address from your Azure virtual network address space. In order to prevent exposure to the public Internet, network traffic between a client on your private network and the app travels over the virtual network and a Private Link on the Microsoft backbone network. To test the connectivity of private endpoint use `nslookup webapp-.azurewebsites.net` in bastion.

[image]

Now, App service is accessible with private endpoint like below:

[image]

This way you can connect privately from Azure and also, from on-prem (if they have a S2S VPN or ExR connection between Azure and on-prem) disable public network access to eliminate public exposure make sure that DNS configuration is in place.

***References***:

[Quickstart: Create a private endpoint - Azure portal - Azure Private Link | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/create-private-endpoint-portal?tabs=dynamic-ip)

[Connect privately to an App Service apps using private endpoint | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking/private-endpoint)

Comment: Thanks Imran. I am able to browse the site though VM which is in same vnet and subnet. But when I do nslookup I get Server: UnKnown Address: 168.63.129.16 and *** UnKnown can't find webapp-.azurewebsites.net: Non-existent domain Also I am not able to browse the site from my laptop even though I am connected to VPN.

Comment: Make sure in your **Private DNS zone** -> under setting Add virtual network links like [this](https://i.imgur.com/QlFzg7m.png)

Comment: I am not able to browse the site from my laptop even though I am connected to VPN you should DNS forwarder to resolve the Azure service and DNS forwarder is a virtual machine on the virtual network linked to the private DNS zone that can proxy DNS queries coming from other virtual networks or from on premises refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-dns#on-premises-workloads-using-a-dns-forwarder) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances?tabs=redhat)

Comment: Hi Imran, Thanks for follow-up. We did try private DNS resolver to query Azure DNS private zones from an on-premises environment and vice versa without deploying VM-based DNS servers. Now when we do nslookup of private link with DNS resolver IP address we get internal IP address and without DNS resolver IP address we get public IP address of Web App in non-authoritative answer. It produce same result without private link also. We have also added conditional forwarding with private link and DNS resolver IP address but still we get forbidden error. not sure what going wrong here.